# Declare a template function taking two objects of a template class friend to (only) those two specializations

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, friend-function

I have a template class `Test` (with an integer as template argument) and a template function (in this case `operator*`) that takes two objects of `Test` class with possibly different template arguments. The function needs to be friend to both its arguments. Here is a minimally working example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N>
class Test;

template <int N1, int N2>
Test<N1+N2> operator* (Test<N1>, Test<N2>);

template <int N>
class Test {
  double val;
public:
  Test (double x) : val{x} {}
  template <int N1, int N2>
  friend Test<N1+N2> operator* (Test<N1>, Test<N2>);
};

template <int N1, int N2>
Test<N1+N2> operator* (Test<N1> x, Test<N2> y) {
  return Test<N1+N2> {x.val*y.val};
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Test<1> a{4.}, c{7.9};
  Test<2> b{3.5};
  a*b;
  a*c;
  return 0;
}
```

This works, but the function is friend to every specializations of `Test`. I want to make it to be friend only with `Test<N1>` and `Test<N2>`.

I tried declaring it like this:

```
template <int N>
class Test {
  double val;
public:
  Test (double x) : val{x} {}
  template <int N1, int N2>
  friend std::enable_if_t<N1==N||N2==N,Test<N1+N2>> operator* (Test<N1>, Test<N2>);
};
```

but encountered g++ errors for ambiguous overloads. I also tried:

```
template <int N>
class Test {
  double val;
public:
  Test (double x) : val{x} {}
  template <int N1, int N2, typename = std::enable_if_t<N1==N||N2==N>>
  friend Test<N1+N2> operator* (Test<N1>, Test<N2>);
};
```

but default template arguments are not allowed for friend declarations.

I prefer a solution in C++14 but solutions in C++17 would also be acceptable.

**Update:** Following the answer of S.M. I suggest the following solution to those with similar problems

```
template <int N>
class Test {
  double val;
public:
  Test (double x) : val{x} {}

  template <int N2>
  Test<N+N2> operator* (Test<N2> y) {
    return Test<N+N2> {val*y.val};
  }

  template <int N2>
  friend class Test;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Test<1> a{4.}, c{7.9};
  Test<2> b{3.5};
  a*b;
  a*c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a strange requirement. So you want those functions which don't satisfy the condition exist but can't access private data ? A reasonable solution is just disable them in the first place.

Comment: I can not understand the requirement. You want the `operator*` being not friend if it is not called? IMHO ambiguous is ok. Removed operator declaration is in one hand and global declaration is in another hand. Compiler can't choose which one to use.

Comment: Why would `operator*<5, 3>` modify private values of a `Test<6>` in the first place? Why do you need to protect from this?

Comment: @liliscent To see why this requirement is needed please see here the problem with approach #1 here https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html

Comment: @S.M. please see the above comment

Comment: @super please see the above comment

Comment: @super This is a minimally working example. The actual code is part of a library for units and dimensions (hence such multiplication). One can specialize the `operator*` and modify the private data of a global object. I wanted to prevent that but if it's not possible I guess I should prevent against accidents not fraud.

Comment: Somebody could also specialize `Test` and there’s really no way to prevent it. See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm, especially the part at the end about Murphy vs. Machiavelli.

Comment: @DanielH Thanks for the link. I get the point. If we befriend all `Test`s then one could specialize `Test` and gain access as in the update, but before that they would have to copy paste essentially everything (or they change implementation of their global objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer the solution bellow. The function is not a friend function any more.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N>
class Test {
  double val;
public:
  Test (double x) : val{x} {}

  template <int N2>
  Test<N+N2> mul(const Test<N2> &y) const {
    return Test<N+N2>{val * y.val};
  }

  template <int N2>
  friend class Test;
};

template <int N1, int N2>
Test<N1+N2> operator* (const Test<N1> &x, const Test<N2> &y) {
  return Test<N1+N2>{x.template mul<N2>(y)};
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Test<1> a{4.}, c{7.9};
  Test<2> b{3.5};
  a*b;
  a*c;
  return 0;
}
```

As a member `operator *`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N>
class Test {
  double val;
public:
  Test (double x) : val{x} {}

  template <int N2>
  Test<N+N2> operator *(const Test<N2> &y) const {
    return Test<N+N2>{val * y.val};
  }

  template <int N2>
  friend class Test;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Test<1> a{4.}, c{7.9};
  Test<2> b{3.5};
  a*b;
  a*c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you provide a reference explaining the use of `template` keyword in `x.template mul<N2>(y)`. And if we are befriending all specializations of Test to each other (which is reasonable) we can also define the multiplication operator as a member rather than non-member, right?

Comment: Yes, we can define the operator as a member function. I did not a member as it is in your answer. Look at my update.

Comment: The answer to your question regarding using `template` keyword look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

**17.5.4 Friends [temp.friend]**

> A friend of a class or class template can be a function template or class template, a specialization of a function template or class template, or a non-template function or class.

Out of these 6 options you might be interesting in function template.

So you can befriend the operator in three ways

```
template <int N1, int N2>
friend Test<N1+N2> operator* (Test<N1>, Test<N2>); #1

template <int N2>
friend Test<N + N2> operator* (Test<N>, Test<N2>); #2

template <int N1>
friend Test<N1 + N> operator* (Test<N1>, Test<N>); #3
```

Option #1 you have tried and it doesn't work as you would like it to. Options #2 and #3 also won't work for two reasons: first, you would need to define this overload somewhere, second, if you define such a overload it would not work with second parameter (#2) and with first parameter (#3).

Comment: #2 and #3 don't declare specializations. They declare different overloads for each possible `N`, and you would somehow need to define them all.

Comment: @aschepler Yeh, you are right these are overloads. Thanks!